# Conditional modification of array in python

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, replace, conditional-statements

I tried to change values in an array when it is in some condition.

For example, I would to like to add 30, when the vlaues are only higher than 10.

So, I tried as follows:

```
x = np.arange(15)
x[x>10] = x + 30
```

I shows "ValueError: NumPy boolean array indexing assignment cannot assign 15 input values to the 4 output values where the mask is true".

Also I tried if else and np.where methods but they also does not work. They seem work only when replacing quantity is a certain value such as 30, not an equation as x + 30.

Any idea or help would be really appreciated.

Thank you,

Isaac

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subset the array before and after the assignment so they have the same length:

```
x[x > 10] = x[x > 10] + 30
x
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 41, 42, 43, 44])
```

Or use [`np.add.at`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.12.0/reference/generated/numpy.ufunc.at.html):

```
np.add.at(x, x > 10, 30)
x
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 41, 42, 43, 44])
```

Use `np.where`, you can do:

```
np.where(x > 10, x + 30, x)
# array([ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10, 41, 42, 43, 44])
```

Comment: Thank you very much Psidom.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the in-place operator `+=` to easily achieve this:

```
x[x>10] += 30
```

Comment: Thank you  very much Graipher,

Answer (score 1):

Remember a Boolean array can also be given numerical operations

```
x += (x > 10) * 30
```

Comment: Thank you very myuch FHTMitchell.